# How can I show an image from assets as a background image when rendering a partial and passing it an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

On the index page:

```
<% @products.each do |prod| %>
  <%= render 'shared/product_card', product: prod %>
<% end %>
```

In my product card partial:

```
<div class="product-card-image" style='background-image: url("<%= product.name %>.jpeg")'></div>
```

I can't hard-code the images into the CSS as background since they are different for each product of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the views you need to call `asset_url(product)` for the URL to render correctly, pointing to the compiled asset.

Please view these docs here to see how to render the assets in different ways: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

Try:

```
<div class="product-card-image" style='background-image: url(<%= asset_path('product.png') %>)'></div>
```

Inline styles are not preferred, If I were you I might try to render the actual image tag for the image in the view, and position it in the div with `object-fit` css directives, placing other content on top of it. This will allow you to avoid the pitfalls of CSP and style tags.

Comment: Ah you're right, I forgot that part. Thanks @3limin4t0r

Comment: I don't want to be nitpicky, but use `asset_path("#{product.name}.jpeg")` to better match the question example.

Comment: Many thanks - yes I went for:
`<div class="product-card-image" style='background-image: url(<%= asset_path("#{product.name.split.join}.jpeg") %>)'></div>`
As I also had spaces in produt names that needed getting rid of